# What about the different interpretations of Bhagavad Gita?

Tags: bhagavad-gita

I came to know that there are around 1500+ interpretations of Bhagavad Gita. Each one is different from the other.

- Is it important to read each and every interpretation of Bhagavad Gita?
- And why it is important for many of us to interpret any particular interpretation so deeply?
- What is the ultimate message of Lord Krishna?

Comment: Why all these religions require damn deep devotion and time ?

Comment: Every individual interprets Gita's slokas in own way. Choose the way which you feel is nearer to God. Though quite popular, I would not recommend ISCKON's version. I find it mileading and biased at many places.

Comment: I am afraid of interpreting it as i wish because i am afraid that there are some illusions sticking to me and my god. I believe certainty is not in our nature. Then what !

Comment: The most authoritative commentary is Sankaracharya's. Reading this should be sufficient.

Comment: Do not worry about right interpretation or wrong interpretation. Everybody interprets as per His own interest and goals as welll as His inner Self guidance. There is nothing like that. Bhagavad Gita is said by whom? A normal human being? NO! God will Himself ensure that you take the right message that is suitable for you! :) Reading is not important, practicing the message is more important. A good person wil take what is good. If one reads any text with an open mind and a good heart, God will Himself Guide You and Answer all your doubts and confusions, isnt it? All the best, good question sir

Comment: @iammilind, biased in what way?

Comment: @sv., the translations are misleading. But ISCKON's other scholars have done a good thing, they also put word by word translations after every sloka. In that way, you get the real meaning instead of sometimes faulty meaning done by Prabhupada. Biased means, their commentaries are revolving around *Krishna*, it doesn't regard anything else. The message of Gita was eternal, even before Krishna was born and even when someone is not aware of him. The interpretation of "Me" in the slokas is done as of "Krishna" as a person. Refer [this answer](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/9162/1049) on "Me".

Answer (score 10):

Ramakrishna Paramahamsa said the following on the ultimate message of the *Gita*. In many ways all the different interpretations would probably agree as to what He says (*Gospel of Sri Ramakrishna*, chapter 3 - *Visit to Vidyasagar* available here: http://www.belurmath.org/gospel/chapter03.htm):

> What is the significance of the *Gita*? It is what you find by repeating the word ten times. It is then reversed into 'tagi', which means a person who has renounced everything for God. And the lesson of the *Gita* is: 'O man, renounce everything and seek God alone.' Whether a man is a monk or a householder, he has to shake off all attachment from his mind.

Comment: Isn't it another interpretation. Why should i believe that Ramakrishna's word are the true message ? And the lesson you mentioned , isn't it from the interpretation ?

Comment: 'tagi' = [tyAgi](http://spokensanskrit.de/index.php?tinput=tyAga&direction=SE&script=HK&link=yes&beginning=)?

Comment: Because the Bhagavad Geeta and many other texts instruct so. Example: Svetashvatara Upanishad (6.23). Paramahamsa Ramakrishna is a self realized person. But you can choose someone else if you wish. When I started my spiritual journey I thought, how do I know whether one person is self realised or not. There is a particular way of testing a Guru. But how to test you have to find out yourself. If you are sincere you will have already encountered this portion in a book or you will very soon. :) best of luck

Answer (score 0):

The objective of Bhagavad Gita is to remove delusion.

Bhagavan Satya Sai explains nicely which is recorded in book Sai Gita, page 23 which you can read [here](https://ia902801.us.archive.org/34/items/SaiBabaGita/Sai%20Baba%20Gita%20%28244%29.pdf)

> Have a clear understanding of the Gita in your heart. **What is the
>   essence of the Gita teachings? Some say that it is the path of service
>   and action, and others say that it is the path of love and devotion.
>   Still others say that it is the path of knowledge and wisdom. But
>   these are all partial truths. The Gita starts with a verse whose first
>   word is dharma, which means duty or right action. The concluding verse
>   of the Gita ends with the word 'my'. When these words are taken
>   together they become 'my duty' or 'my work'. That summarizes the whole
>   teaching of the Gita. It means you should perform your prescribed duty
>   to the very limits of the human capacity for excellence and
>   perfection, doing the work that is appropriate to your stage of life.**
>   When you are a student study your lessons well. When you are a
>   householder perform your work and family responsibilities properly.
>   When you are retired perform the duties appropriate to that stage, and
>   if you have renounced the world to engage yourself in contemplation of
>   the reality, then stick to that path. When you follow your prescribed
>   duty in the very best way possible, discharging your duty sincerely
>   and conscientiously, then there will be no confusion or misery. Arjuna
>   had to perform his duty on the battlefield. His calling was to be a
>   warrior and to combat evil and protect the good. But, when he saw his
>   friends and relations arrayed on both sides of the battlefield, he
>   forgot his strong resolve to fight for right, the fight for which he
>   had been preparing for so long. He became full of attachments and
>   delusion, and threw down his bow. He abandoned his duty and became
>   miserable. Krishna taught Arjuna how to free himself from despair by
>   adhering to his prescribed duty. Krishna taught Arjuna the truth of
>   the immortal self, and showed him that his duty was to follow the
>   inner promptings of the Lord, who was enshrined in his heart. When
>   Krishna finished his teachings, he asked Arjuna, "Have your
>   attachments and delusions disappeared?" Arjuna picked up his bow and
>   answered, "My despair has completely vanished. All my delusion is now
>   gone. I will do as you command!" As long as you have delusion you will
>   be in a state of bondage. When you suffer from delusion and
>   infatuation, liberation is impossible. Liberation has nothing to do
>   with worldly pleasures. It is not an air-conditioned car or a
>   comfortable life. It is the complete destruction of delusion. i.It is
>   the extinction of all worldly attachments, the incineration of all
>   selfish desires. From now on, do your duty to perfection and become
>   ideals for mankind. Apply the teachings of the Gita in your daily life
>   and be blessed with grace. Many of you are just wasting your time.
>   Start today to reform yourself. Don't waste time. Time is God. Every
>   day spend some time on these holy teachings and contemplate their
>   inner meaning. Once they are understood, put them into practice. Only
>   in this way will you be able to attain a sacred life, a life of purity
>   and perfection, which is the mark of a true human being.

This is the most widely appreciated teaching of Gita appreciated by all classes of people.

Comment: Great answer... I wonder why no body upvoted this.